# Adding decreasing power of the same number

Tags: exponentiation, geometric-series

Simpler ways of writing for example $a^{n}$ + $a^{n-1}$ + $a^ {n-2}$ + ... + a=

what is this even called ?

Comment: So basically this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series (notice that summation is commutative, so you can just flip the order around)

Comment: @MattiP. I've seen "series" used mainly in the infinite sum context. In this case, "geometric sum" is better.

Comment: "Sum of a geometric progression" is what I would say.

Answer (score 1):

This is a (finite) geometric series, which can be given by the formula
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}a^k= \frac{a(1-a^n)}{1-a} \, .
$$